# Why does sphinx conf.py gives me an error for trying to import sys

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to create a simple documentation with sphinx and autodoc, but the autodoc could not improt my modules. Figure that is because i did not add the path to the modules into sys path  in conf.py

So i went and add this at the start of conf.py:

```
 import sys
 import os
 sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
```

and now i am getting the following error on the line with import sys and i have no idea why,since i have the same code as in sphinxs example.

```
Configuration error:
There is a syntax error in your configuration file: bad input (conf.py, line 20)
Did you change the syntax from 2.x to 3.x?
```

line 20 is the line with import sys, before it are only autogenerated comments

Comment: Did you read it? The error jumps up on the line where i am importing sys, changing the string does not do anything, i tried to run it before just with the default value there : import sys
 sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.')) which resulted in the same error

Comment: ...Is there a space before `import sys`? Like ` import sys`?

Comment: What error do you get when you execute `conf.py` directly?

Comment: @Rawing lol yes that was the case... the autogenerated comments had one more space before the code that i did not notice, so erasing only the # did not work...

Comment: after removing spaces before import statements it's working as expected

Answer (score 2):

Autogenerated commented code had one space between the code and the comment symbol # which i did not notice.

Answer (score 0):

In conf.py, after removing spaces before import statements it's working as expected